# Getting the row in a gallery with custom adapter in Android

Tags: java, android

I am making a personalized gallery and I am having trouble whenever I try to load an image from the gallery (I call another activity with a parameter on it to know which image has to load). The problem is that the image displayed is not the one that should be. The question I have is, how do I keep track of the row where my images are?

I create my gallery in the MainActivity program

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView gallery;
ArrayList<Photo> row = new ArrayList<Photo>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);        

    gallery = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvdata);

    init();

    gallery.setAdapter(new PhotoAdapter(getBaseContext(), row));
}
```

and then I use a holder to keep track of my images (inside the PhotoAdapter class) :

```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    positionAbs=position;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_photo, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();            
        holder.iv1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        holder.iv2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv2);
        holder.iv3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv3);
        holder.iv4 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv4);
        holder.row = position;


        final int rowL=holder.row;
        holder.iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                val=1;
                loadIntent(calculaPos(rowL,val));

            }                      
        });  
        holder.iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                val=2;
                loadIntent(calculaPos(rowL,val));

            }
        });   

        holder.iv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                val=3;
                loadIntent(calculaPos(rowL,val));

            }
        });   

        holder.iv4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                val=4;
                loadIntent(calculaPos(rowL,val));

            }
        });                 
        convertView.setTag(holder);

     } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

    holder.iv1.setImageResource(list.get(position).getIv1());
    holder.iv2.setImageResource(list.get(position).getIv2());
    holder.iv3.setImageResource(list.get(position).getIv3());
    holder.iv4.setImageResource(list.get(position).getIv4());

    pos1=list.get(position).getIv1();
    pos2=list.get(position).getIv2();
    pos3=list.get(position).getIv3();
    pos4=list.get(position).getIv4();





    return convertView;
}
```

I would like to know if there's any way to, whenever I create a new holder, keep track of the row number of the holder.

*EDIT* The approach I've taken is to add to my gallery a listener to know when gets clicked, like this:

```
    gallery.setAdapter(new PhotoAdapter(getBaseContext(), row));
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
        {                   
                System.out.println(">> column value is "+arg2);
                            //arg2 is the image position

        }  

    });}
```

The problem is, now I can't access my local values in the adapter I've made (it has 4 photos in each row) but I can get the row I am clicking (disabling the onClickListener inside the PhotoAdapter). Is there any way to activate both listeners at the same time? This way I would be able to get the row of the picture on my main activity class and the column of the picture inside the adapter class.

Thanks for reading!